# A sequence $f_n$ can converge in distribution to two different limits f, g, that are not equal almost everywhere.

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve an exercise from Tao's measure theory book, and I am stuck to the following question:
"Show that a sequence $f_n$ can converge in distribution to two different limits f, g, that are not equal almost everywhere."

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the central limit theorem: $X_n$ are i.i.d squared integrable random variables with variance 1, $Z$ is a standard normal distribution, then we have
$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{\sqrt{n}}$ converge in distriubtion to $Z$ as well as to $-Z$

Comment: Hmm, I don't get how Z and -Z actually differ from each other?

Comment: @morfara: they are equal in distribution, but for a given $\omega$, $Z(\omega) \neq - Z(\omega)$ almost surely since $P(Z=0)=0$